# Button is always disabled using CompositeCommand in Prism5 with WPF

Tags: wpf, prism-5

Hi I wrote code for view navigation, For that i added button on my navigation area on that button click i want to open view in content area My code is

ModuleCode

```
public class ClientModule : ModuleBase
    { 

        public ClientModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
            : base(container, regionManager) { }       

        protected override void InitializeModule()
        {
            RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("NavigationRegion", typeof(Navigation));
            RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(Content));          
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            Container.RegisterType<object, Navigation>(typeof(Navigation).FullName);
           Container.RegisterType<object,Content>(typeof(Content).FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Bootstrap is

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return this.Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            base.ConfigureContainer();
            Container.RegisterType<IShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>();
        }

        protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
        {
            RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
            mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(StackPanel), Container.Resolve<StackPanelRegionAdapter>());
            return mappings;
        }


        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ClientModule));
        }


    }
```

and my navigationview have 1 button as below

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{x:Static infCommands:ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{x:Type views:Content}" 
            Name="btnTest">Navigate to Content</Button>

</StackPanel>
```

now problem is when i run my application button always show disable, Can any one tell me what is the problem and what is its solution.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `Command="{x:Static infCommands:ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand}"` instead of just `Command="{ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand}"`? See the [ApplicationCommands Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Its coming from namespace infCommand, If i will not add "x:Static infCommands:" this is giving me bunch of errors.Because its not exposed. here is code for Application command class  public class ApplicationCommands
    {
        public static CompositeCommand NavigateCommand = new CompositeCommand();
    }

Comment: can you post viewmodel code, Before that for all your commands you need canexecute to be triggered whenever your data is changed or try putting return true in all canexecutes of commands

Comment: I am getting same error, for the same code. The code comes from pluralsight examples. Have you found the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. 
I was using same code following a pluralsight video about Prism.

Issue was that the only commmand associated with CompositeCommand was not set to Active. After setting IsActive to true, CompositeCommand became active, and button was enabled.

Following is from msdn docs for [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx)
`The CompositeCommand can be configured to evaluate the active status of child DelegateCommands (in addition to the CanExecute status) by specifying true for the monitorCommandActivity parameter in the constructor. When this parameter is set to true, the CompositeCommand class will consider each child DelegateCommand's active status when determining the return value for the CanExecute method and when executing child commands within the Execute method.
When the monitorCommandActivity parameter is true, the CompositeCommand class exhibits the following behavior:
CanExecute. Returns true only when all active commands can be executed. Child commands that are inactive will not be considered at all.
Execute. Executes all active commands. Child commands that are inactive will not be considered at all.`